# Prevent Excel from altering formulas to #REF on opening the referenced workbook

Tags: excel, sharepoint, reference

Excel changes formulas when I open the referenced workbook, and wont change them back. Original Formula:

```
=IF(condition;'\\sharepoint.host.com\path\[Filename.xlsx]Sheetname'!A1;"")
```

by Excel modified formula:

```
=IF(condition;'\\sharepoint.host.com\path\[Filename.xlsx]#REF'!A1;"")
```

I have a few hundred of those formulas and already made a VBA-script to replace all occurences of "#REF" by the correct SheetName, so technically I have a workaround. And it works well.

But WTF?!? Why would Excel do this? And how can I stop/prevent this?
This is not related to copying cells within Excel.

Comment: To me, the actual wtf-moment is that if i dont pay attention to this, and save other changes, the original formulas are lost. LOST! Excel on purpose deletes contet of my sheet! Am I the only user WTFfing about this??

Answer (score 0):

Excel will put #REF when a sheet is deleted or, for some reason, becomes inaccessible.

The same happens if a cell is deleted. Had this happen when I have deleted the wrong column by accident. One reason I only ever work on a copy and keep backups.